# How do I achieve navigation on React mobile app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a React App for desktop and mobile. When the app is displayed on a desktop. Below is the desktop view that I get.
[image]

When the same app is displayed on a mobile, How can I achieve the below mobile views ? I am looking on some pointers on the modules and some guidance on how I can achieve this ?

Do I hide and unhide components  ?
How can I link the navigation and the components ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you found a solution for this @kurrodu ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with the `@media` of css to achieve it, and so it deployed the informations of a doctor when it s clicked.

It will be the most simple way to do it